# Characteristic function of simplicial complex

Tags: simplicial-complex

Is there some sort of explicit (ideally polynomial) characteristic function of simplicial complexes?

Let $C = \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{1,2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1,3\}, \{3, 4\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \emptyset\}$. Here we have a filled triangle $(1,2,3)$ and an edge $(3,4)$. I'm looking for indicator function $f(s) = 1 \Leftrightarrow s \in C$

Comment: Any polynomial function would be continuous, and so not be the characteristic function of any proper nonempty subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Which is the domain of definition of $f$?

Comment: dan_fulea, it might be the set of all simplicial complexes, or a set of simplicial complexes on n (in my example n = 4) vertices.